# "Cocos2d" copied actions not responding?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am running an animation on 2 sprites, like so:

```
-(void) startFootballAnimation {

CCAnimation* footballAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrame:@"Football" frameCount:60 delay:0.005f];
spiral = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:footballAnim];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:spiral];
[self runAction:repeat];
[secondFootball runAction:[[repeat copy] autorelease]];
}
```

The problem I am having is that, when I call this method:

```
    - (void) slowAnimation {

[spiral setDuration:[spiral duration] + 0.01];
}
```

....it only slows down the first sprite's animation and not the second one. Do I need to do something different with copied actions to get them to react to the slowing of the animation?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you should use 2 actions for two different objects. Otherwise you can't distinguish between them. Although I am not 100% positive.

Comment: That would mean that I would have to create the exact same action for another sprite!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling copy on the `repeat` object also copies the inner action.  You can see this by looking at `CCRepeatForever`'s implementation of `copyWithZone:` in CCAction.m.  This is good because an action can only have one target node.

So yes, to answer your question in comments above, you do need to create the a new action for each sprite.  You can use the copy method to quickly replicate your actions, but you'll have to apply changes to their behavior (e.g. your `slowAnimation` stuff) individually.